# Select Data where the diffence between to different date field are less then 2 hours Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know how many customers have placed an order within 2 hours compared to their registration date.

both date types have ddmmyyyy hh:mi

Comment: Very Wrong way to put your question,Please go through on how to Ask Questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 Select Count(*) from WhateverYourTable where (24)*(Orderdate-RegisteredDate)>2
```